# Apache stops with error: Terminating threads that failed to exit

Tags: php, multithreading, apache, xampp

I have a problem with an PHP script, running in XAMPP Apache. The Script runs without errors and need to be repeated infinitely. Sometimes the script runs perfect 100 times, sometimes 20 times and sometimes just 5 times. But there will be always the situation when the script will be terminated by Apache with the error "Terminating (#) threads that failed to exit.". Then I have to restart the script manually.

Has anyone an idea, how I can solve this issue?

The error occurs after I upgraded my machine. On my old machine the script runs without this error.

There is no differnce in the config or installed versions. The new machine has more RAM, CPU and space.

There is enough free RAM, CPU and space available while running the script.

This is the Apache log (it always looks like this):

```
[Tue Sep 27 14:36:01.748279 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10664:tid 268] AH00354: Child: Starting 250 worker threads.
[Tue Sep 27 14:36:31.886002 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12924:tid 268] AH00362: Child: Waiting 270 more seconds for 2 worker threads to finish.
[Tue Sep 27 14:37:01.919720 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12924:tid 268] AH00362: Child: Waiting 240 more seconds for 2 worker threads to finish.
[Tue Sep 27 14:37:32.041443 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12924:tid 268] AH00362: Child: Waiting 210 more seconds for 2 worker threads to finish.
[Tue Sep 27 14:38:02.114163 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12924:tid 268] AH00362: Child: Waiting 180 more seconds for 2 worker threads to finish.
[Tue Sep 27 14:38:32.131880 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12924:tid 268] AH00362: Child: Waiting 150 more seconds for 2 worker threads to finish.
[Tue Sep 27 14:39:02.139596 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12924:tid 268] AH00362: Child: Waiting 120 more seconds for 2 worker threads to finish.
[Tue Sep 27 14:39:32.203316 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12924:tid 268] AH00362: Child: Waiting 90 more seconds for 2 worker threads to finish.
[Tue Sep 27 14:40:02.254035 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12924:tid 268] AH00362: Child: Waiting 60 more seconds for 2 worker threads to finish.
[Tue Sep 27 14:40:32.326755 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12924:tid 268] AH00362: Child: Waiting 30 more seconds for 2 worker threads to finish.
[Tue Sep 27 14:41:02.393475 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12924:tid 268] AH00362: Child: Waiting 0 more seconds for 2 worker threads to finish.
[Tue Sep 27 14:41:02.493480 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12924:tid 268] AH00363: Child: Terminating 2 threads that failed to exit.
[Tue Sep 27 14:41:02.493480 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12924:tid 268] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
```

I tried to change the number of working threads, from 200-2000, always the same result.

Is there a way to increase the amount of time that Apache "waits for worker threads to finish"?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
I have a local MySQL database with productdata for an onlineshop. The script refreshes the productinformations and creates a CSV file for uploading them.

Comment: Why do you use an http server to execute a permanently executing script? That makes little sense, does it?

Comment: I have a local MySQL database with productdata for an onlineshop. The script refreshes the productinformations and creates a CSV file for uploading them.

Comment: Please add additional information to the question. Do not hide it in comments. Thanks.